# Titanium - BUILD FAILED 'Ld build/Debug-iphoneos/my.app/my normal armv7'

Tags: titanium

I'm using ***Ti.BlurView 0.35*** (bencoding.blur-iphone-0.35) with my alloy based project, and got an error when compiling and installing the app on my iphone5C.

here is the error log:

```
[ERROR] : ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] : The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] : Ld build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app/myapp normal armv7
[ERROR] : (1 failure)
```

I've tried to create a clean alloy based project, just moved the Ti.BlurView module to the ***myapp/modules/iphone*** folder and add the reference in the tiapp.xml:

```
<modules>
    <module platform="iphone">bencoding.blur</module>
</modules>
```

It would cause the ld error.

And also I've tried things like clean the project which didn't work for me.

Here is my building environment:

- titanium SDK: 3.2.3.GA
- alloy: 1.3.1
- xcode: 5.1.1
- osx: 10.9.2

Testing environment:

- iphone5C: running iOS 7.1.1

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure that out.

Rebuilding the project from Xcode that provide detailed error messages:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TiUIImageViewProxy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BencodingBlurGPUBlurImageViewProxy in libbencoding.blur.a(BencodingBlurGPUBlurImageViewProxy.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BencodingBlurBasicBlurViewProxy in libbencoding.blur.a(BencodingBlurBasicBlurViewProxy.o)

...
```

Check out the ***TiUIImageViewProxy.h***, it wasn't included in the target application.
It seems you should have create an `<ImageView>` in advance, and everything works.